# Checking input against list elements in Python

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to make a simple program which first checks to see if a user's input matches a list and then will check what element of the list that input matches and gives a response based on the input. The part I'm having trouble with is, coming up with a way to see what element of the list the input matches, so that I can give a certain response based off of that input. I really would appreciate any help I can get with this problem.

Thanks, Nova

This is my current code that I have so far. Under the first if statement is where I would like to put the check for what element of the list matches the input.

```
Y = ["How", "Hi", "Hey", "How are you doing", "How's it going", "How", "Hello"]
I = str(input("Start Conversation"))

if I in Y:
    print("Working");

elif I not in Y:
    print("I don't Understand");
```

Comment: If the input matches something from your list, why not simply use the input itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's excellent `list.index` function:

```
if I in Y:
  print("Working" + str(Y.index(I)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is simple and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can throw it in as a one-liner if you want:

```
Y = ["How", "Hi", "Hey", "How are you doing", "How's it going", "How", "Hello"]
I = str(input("Start Conversation"))

print("Working:", I) if I in Y else print("I don't understand")
```

As Thmei has already noted, the `if` matches `I` against `Y`, so you already know that the content of `I` is in the list and it can be printed. If you would prefer to output the actual index of `I` in `Y` (if it exists), you can do this:

```
print(Y.index(I)) if I in Y else print("I don't understand")
```

Or the long way:

```
if I in Y:
    print (Y.index(I))
else:
    print ("I don't understand")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already matched `I` against the items in your list, if `I` matched one of them, it will be the same as the item it matched.

```
print(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in Y:
      if I == a:
            #do something
```